Mongodb connection failed while running with docker-compose
This is my server.js file:
let path = require('path');
let fs = require('fs');
let MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"));
  });

  
app.get('/profile-picture', function (req, res) {
  let img = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "images/profile-1.jpg"));
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpg' });
  res.end(img, 'binary');
});
let mongoUrlLocal = "mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017";
let mongoUrlDocker = "mongodb://admin:password@mongodb";
let mongoClientOptions = { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true };
let databaseName = "user-account";

app.post('/update-profile', function (req, res) {
  let userObj = req.body;
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:8080', function (err, client) {
    if (err) throw err;

    let db = client.db(databaseName);
    userObj['userid'] = 1;

    let myquery = { userid: 1 };
    let newvalues = { $set: userObj };

    db.collection("users").updateOne(myquery, newvalues, {upsert: true}, function(err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;
      client.close();
    });

  });
  // Send response
  res.send(userObj);
});

app.get('/get-profile', function (req, res) {
  let response = {};
  // Connect to the db
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://admin:password@localhost:8080', function (err, client) {
    if (err) throw err;

    let db = client.db(databaseName);

    let myquery = { userid: 1 };

    db.collection("users").findOne(myquery, function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      response = result;
      client.close();

      // Send response
      res.send(response ? response : {});
    });
  });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("app listening on port 3000!");
});

This is my docker-compose.yml file
version: '3'
services:
  # my-app:
  # image: ${docker-registry}/my-app:1.0
  # ports:
  # - 3000:3000
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always # fixes MongoNetworkError when mongodb is not ready when mongo-express starts
    ports:
      - 8080:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
volumes:
  mongo-data:
    driver: local

This is the Dockerfile:

ENV MONGO_DB_USERNAME=admin \
    MONGO_DB_PWD=password

RUN mkdir -p /home/app

COPY ./app /home/app
WORKDIR /home/app
RUN npm install
CMD ["node", "server.js"]


When I run docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up getting this error:
ms","Start up the replication coordinator":"6 ms","Start transport layer":"2 ms","_initAndListen total elapsed time":"909 ms"}}}}        
mongo-express-1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: mongo: Try again
mongo-express-1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Invalid argument
mongo-express-1  | Wed Apr  3 01:27:38 UTC 2024 retrying to connect to mongo:27017 (2/10)
mongo-express-1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: mongo: Try again
mongo-express-1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Invalid argument
mongo-express-1  | Wed Apr  3 01:27:44 UTC 2024 retrying to connect to mongo:27017 (3/10)
mongo-express-1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: mongo: Try again
mongo-express-1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Invalid argument
mongo-express-1  | Wed Apr  3 01:27:50 UTC 2024 retrying to connect to mongo:27017 (4/10)
mongo-express-1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: mongo: Try again
mongo-express-1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Invalid argument
mongo-express-1  | Wed Apr  3 01:27:56 UTC 2024 retrying to connect to mongo:27017 (5/10)
mongo-express-1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: mongo: Name does not resolve
mongo-express-1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Invalid argument
mongo-express-1  | Wed Apr  3 01:28:00 UTC 2024 retrying to connect to mongo:27017 (6/10)
mongo-express-1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: mongo: Name does not resolve
mongo-express-1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Invalid argument
mongo-express-1  | Wed Apr  3 01:28:05 UTC 2024 retrying to connect to mongo:27017 (7/10)
mongo-express-1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: mongo: Try again
mongo-express-1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Invalid argument
mongo-express-1  | Wed Apr  3 01:28:11 UTC 2024 retrying to connect to mongo:27017 (8/10)
mongo-express-1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: mongo: Try again
mongo-express-1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Invalid argument
mongo-express-1  | Wed Apr  3 01:28:17 UTC 2024 retrying to connect to mongo:27017 (9/10)
mongo-express-1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: mongo: Try again
mongo-express-1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Invalid argument
mongo-express-1  | Wed Apr  3 01:28:23 UTC 2024 retrying to connect to mongo:27017 (10/10)
mongo-express-1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: mongo: Try again
mongo-express-1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Invalid argument
mongo-express-1  | No custom config.js found, loading config.default.js
mongo-express-1  | Welcome to mongo-express 1.0.2

And unable to run this app at port 3000 with node server.js It goes into app listening at port 3000 but on the browser it's all empty.
Reference for this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3c-iBn73dDE&t=7223s

In your docker-compose.yml, try adding depends_on:
- mongodb
right under mongo-express->environment

#@MalcolmInTheCenter this didn't work
    - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
    - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
    - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
  depends_on:
    - mongodb```

It gave you the same error?

Yes, the same error pops up

are you destroying the containers before running the docker-compose -f command?

I think you missed configuring the Mongo port.
Add the following line:
ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT=27017

Yes, I'm deleting the containers before stating with compose

and ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT=27017 this doesn't work either, getting same error

Fundamentally, the mongo-express Docker image is buggy.
While the mongo-express app itself will use ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER if is set (and will prefer that over ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL), the entrypoint script (/docker-entrypoint.sh) only uses ME_CONFIG_MONDODB_URL. It contains the following code:
if [[ "$ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL" != *,* ]]; then
    work=$ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL
    # Remove the scheme (should be "mongodb://" or "mongodb+srv://").
    work=${work#*://}
    # Remove the path component of the URL (should just be a "/").
    work=${work%%/*}
    # Remove the userinfo.
    work=${work#*@}
    if [[ "$work" = *:* ]]; then
        # Match the host.
        host=${work%:*}
        # Match the port.
        port=${work#*:}
    else
        host=$work
        port=27017
    fi

    # wait for the mongo server to be available
    echo "Waiting for $host:$port..."
    wait_tcp_port "$host" "$port" "${ME_CONFIG_CONNECT_RETRIES:-10}"
fi

The image also sets a default value for ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL of mongodb://mongo:27017. Since you're setting ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER but not setting ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL, the entrypoint gets stuck waiting to connect to server mongo based on that default value.
We can fix that by providing an appropriate value to ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL:
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always # fixes MongoNetworkError when mongodb is not ready when mongo-express starts
    ports:
      - 8080:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: admin
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: password
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongodb
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://mongodb:27017
volumes:
  mongo-data:

The above compose file successfully brings up mongo-express.
You could also have resolved this by renaming your mongodb service to mongo, which would make it match the defaults.
